# F12 developer tools in IE9 not working for some sites

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I can launch the F12 developer tools in IE9, but for some sites, they don't do anything. The window opens but sits with the word "Loading..." in the HTML tab, and none of the controls work.

Any idea what might be wrong?

**UPDATE** I checked the network tab with Chrome and do not see any hanging requests.  Further, the page itself is responsive in IE.

Comment: Try using firefox or Chrome and see if it shows what is slow to download.

Comment: @wrschneider99 Is the page online, someplace we can access it?

Comment: Ok, I can't show you my own application - but facebook.com is giving me the same problem.

Comment: @wrschneider99 I just pulled up facebook and it loaded fine. The problem may be with your network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out - the problem was that I have Google Chrome Frame installed, and that certain sites were activating it, which was effectively taking over the DOM/CSS rendering.

I didn't realize it was still there, because it wasn't showing up under Tools/Manage Add-Ons to disable.  After uninstalling cleanly, everything works again.

So my own mistake with my environment.

Comment: Disabling it works, too. Either way you go - uninstall or just disable - you need to start with a fresh tab/window so you're not using the running instance of GCF.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a resource on your page that is hanging, and preventing the tools from loading completely. Wait for these resources to timeout, and/or consider downloading something like [Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com) to watch your network traffic. Look for files that are being requested, but delaying the loading of the page by a great deal.